# Deployment to AWS ECS using Github Actions is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, github-actions, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have written a github actions workflow yaml file by following this guide. The workflow file is added below:-

```
name: Deploy to Staging Amazon ECS

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging

env:
  ECR_REPOSITORY: api-staging-jruby/api
  ECS_CLUSTER: api_staging
  J_RUBY_ECS_SERVICE: web-staging
  J_RUBY_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: infrastructure/staging/web-jruby-task-definition.json
  J_RUBY_CONTAINER_NAME: api-staging-jruby
  ANALYTICS_ECS_SERVICE: analytics-staging
  ANALYTICS_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: infrastructure/staging/analytics-task-definition.json
  ANALYTICS_CONTAINER_NAME: analytics-staging
  WORKER_ECS_SERVICE: worker-staging
  WORKER_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: infrastructure/staging/worker-task-definition.json
  WORKER_CONTAINER_NAME: sidekiq-staging
  CONSOLE_ECS_SERVICE: console-staging
  CONSOLE_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: infrastructure/staging/console-task-definition.json
  CONSOLE_CONTAINER_NAME: api-console-staging

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: staging

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@13d241b293754004c80624b5567555c4a39ffbe3
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@aaf69d68aa3fb14c1d5a6be9ac61fe15b48453a2

      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        id: build-image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
        run: |
          # Build a docker container and
          # push it to ECR so that it can
          # be deployed to ECS.
          docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
          echo "image=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition (JRuby)
        id: task-def-jruby
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1.1.2
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ env.J_RUBY_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
          container-name: ${{ env.J_RUBY_CONTAINER_NAME }}
          image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

      - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition (JRuby)
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1.4.10
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def-jruby.outputs.task-definition }}
          service: ${{ env.J_RUBY_ECS_SERVICE }}
          cluster: ${{ env.ECS_CLUSTER }}
          wait-for-service-stability: true
      
      - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition (Analytics)
        id: task-def-analytics
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1.1.2
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ env.ANALYTICS_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
          container-name: ${{ env.ANALYTICS_CONTAINER_NAME }}
          image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

      - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition (Analytics)
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1.4.10
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def-analytics.outputs.task-definition }}
          service: ${{ env.ANALYTICS_ECS_SERVICE }}
          cluster: ${{ env.ECS_CLUSTER }}
          wait-for-service-stability: true

      - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition (Worker)
        id: task-def-worker
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1.1.2
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ env.WORKER_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
          container-name: ${{ env.WORKER_CONTAINER_NAME }}
          image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

      - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition (Worker)
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1.4.10
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def-worker.outputs.task-definition }}
          service: ${{ env.WORKER_ECS_SERVICE }}
          cluster: ${{ env.ECS_CLUSTER }}
          wait-for-service-stability: true

      - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition (Console)
        id: task-def-console
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1.1.2
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ env.CONSOLE_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
          container-name: ${{ env.CONSOLE_CONTAINER_NAME }}
          image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

      - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition (Worker)
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1.4.10
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def-console.outputs.task-definition }}
          service: ${{ env.CONSOLE_ECS_SERVICE }}
          cluster: ${{ env.ECS_CLUSTER }}
          wait-for-service-stability: true
```

The workflow is failing in the step Deploy Amazon ECS task definition (JRuby) and I am unable to debug the cause of the issue.

I have also confirmed the image is uploaded into ECR. I turned on the debug logs to check them. Here's is the stack track:-

```
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Deploy Amazon ECS task definition (JRuby)'
##[debug]Evaluating: success()
##[debug]Evaluating success:
##[debug]=> true
##[debug]Result: true
##[debug]Starting: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition (JRuby)
##[debug]Loading inputs
##[debug]Evaluating: steps.task-def-jruby.outputs.task-definition
##[debug]Evaluating Index:
##[debug]..Evaluating Index:
##[debug]....Evaluating Index:
##[debug]......Evaluating steps:
##[debug]......=> Object
##[debug]......Evaluating String:
##[debug]......=> 'task-def-jruby'
##[debug]....=> Object
##[debug]....Evaluating String:
##[debug]....=> 'outputs'
##[debug]..=> Object
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'task-definition'
##[debug]=> '/home/runner/work/_temp/task-definition--16224-xjXb92vYNt3B-.json'
##[debug]Result: '/home/runner/work/_temp/task-definition--16224-xjXb92vYNt3B-.json'
##[debug]Evaluating: env.J_RUBY_ECS_SERVICE
##[debug]Evaluating Index:
##[debug]..Evaluating env:
##[debug]..=> Object
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'J_RUBY_ECS_SERVICE'
##[debug]=> 'web-staging'
##[debug]Result: 'web-staging'
##[debug]Evaluating: env.ECS_CLUSTER
##[debug]Evaluating Index:
##[debug]..Evaluating env:
##[debug]..=> Object
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'ECS_CLUSTER'
##[debug]=> 'api_staging'
##[debug]Result: 'api_staging'
##[debug]Loading env
Run aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1.4.10
##[debug]Registering the task definition

::set-output name=task-definition-arn::arn:aws:ecs:***:***:task-definition/web-staging-jruby:91
Warning: The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/
##[debug]='arn:aws:ecs:***:***:task-definition/web-staging-jruby:91'
##[debug]Updating the service
Error: The container api-staging does not exist in the task definition.
##[debug]InvalidParameterException: The container api-staging does not exist in the task definition.
##[debug]    at Request.extractError (/home/runner/work/_actions/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition/v1.4.10/dist/index.js:19497:27)
##[debug]    at Request.callListeners (/home/runner/work/_actions/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition/v1.4.10/dist/index.js:22778:20)
##[debug]    at Request.emit (/home/runner/work/_actions/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition/v1.4.10/dist/index.js:22750:10)
##[debug]    at Request.emit (/home/runner/work/_actions/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition/v1.4.10/dist/index.js:21384:14)
##[debug]    at Request.transition (/home/runner/work/_actions/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition/v1.4.10/dist/index.js:20720:10)
##[debug]    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/runner/work/_actions/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition/v1.4.10/dist/index.js:27746:12)
##[debug]    at /home/runner/work/_actions/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition/v1.4.10/dist/index.js:27758:10
##[debug]    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition/v1.4.10/dist/index.js:20736:9)
##[debug]    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition/v1.4.10/dist/index.js:21386:12)
##[debug]    at Request.callListeners (/home/runner/work/_actions/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition/v1.4.10/dist/index.js:22788:18)
##[debug]Node Action run completed with exit code 1
##[debug]Finishing: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition (JRuby)
```

As you can see from the above stack trace that `api-staging` is nowhere mentioned in the workflow yaml file. This is the reason I am unable to debug it. We are already deploying manually using a shell-script. So we are reusing the same cluster and services. There is a chance `api-staging` is coming from AWS but I am not 100% sure.

Edit:

Content of `web-jruby-task-definition.json`:

```
{
  "cpu": "2048",
  "memory": "5120",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
       "FARGATE"
    ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "api-staging-jruby",
      "image": "<account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/api-staging/api:latest",
      "dockerLabels": {
                    "com.datadoghq.ad.instances": "[{\"host\": \"%%host%%\", \"port\": 8000}]",
                    "com.datadoghq.ad.check_names": "[\"api-staging\"]",
                    "com.datadoghq.ad.init_configs": "[{}]"
                },
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 8000,
          "hostPort": 8000
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "api-staging",
          "awslogs-region": "<region>",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "jruby-staging-api"
        }
      },
      "secrets": [
        {
          "name": "ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL",
          "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<account_id>:secret:staging/ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL-<id>"
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "datadog-agent",
      "image": "datadog/agent:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "secrets": [
        {
          "name": "DD_API_KEY",
          "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<account_id>:secret:staging/environment-name-<id>"
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ],
  "family": "web-staging-jruby"
}
```

Comment: You have 4 task definition .json files. One of those, it looks like `web-jruby-task-definition.json` appears to have a reference in it to a container named `api-staging` (probably a reference in a `dependsOn` setting would be my guess) but there is no container defined in it named `api-staging`. You need to include the content of that .json file in your question if you want us to show you how to fix it.

Comment: Hey @MarkB Thanks for your reply. I have added the content of `web-jruby-task-definition.json` in the question.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong. It sort of looks like this setting in the GitHub action: `container-name: ${{ env.J_RUBY_CONTAINER_NAME }}` is evaluating to `api-staging` instead of `api-staging-jruby`, but I don't have the slightest idea why. You could try hard-coding the container name in that action to see if that changes anything.